# CSS Transition Property is only working one way

Tags: css, sass

CSS transition property is only working in one direction on `<details>` tag -- when opening. No transition when closing. I've tested on Chrome & Firefox.

To add, on Chrome, the opening transition only works once.

```
details
    position: relative
    ul
        position: absolute
        bottom: 100%
        left: 0
        height: 300px
        display: flex
        flex-direction: column
        transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out
        transform-origin: bottom
        transform: scaleY(0)
    &[open]
        ul
            transform: scaleY(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `details` tag works by instantly showing and hiding its contents. When you close it, the contents immediately disappear so no transition is witnessed.